# How to launch multiple different URL on a page with auto bot login using .VBS?

Tags: vbscript, scripting, autologin

Seeking for your assistance in editing the below set. Plan is to create multiple different url auto bot login in one page only. (e.g. auto login to yahoo.com, gmail.com, facebook.com and etc...) just in one webpage browser IE

```
set a = createobject ("wscript.shell")
a.run "URL"
wscript.sleep (5000)
a.sendkeys ("username")
a.sendkeys chr (9)
wscript.sleep (2000)
a.sendkeys ("password")
a.sendkeys "{Enter}"
wscript.quit
```

- have 5 tools that I am using in my job and they are username password protected. Since I use them daily I would like to create a bot login-     Need your expertise here fellas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the SendKeys method. You can get the ID off the username box and the password box by inspect element for each site by using the `.value` method. Like this `ie.Doucment.All.Item("email").Value= "Password goes in here"`.

Facebook:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie
ie = CreatObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Sub WhilD
Do While ie.busy
wscript.sleep 200
loop
End Sub
ie.Navigate "www.facebook.com"
Call WhilD
ie.Document.All.Item("email").value = "Facebook username goes here"
ie.Document.All.Item("pass").value = "Facebook password goes here"
ie.Document.All.Item("login_form").submit
Call WhilD
ie.navOpenInNewWindow = 1
Call WhilD
ie.Document.All.Item("Email").value = "Gmail username goes here"
ie.Document.All.Item("Passwd").value = "Gmail password goes here"
ie.Document.All.Item("SignIn").Submit
wscript.quit
```

email is the HTML ID for the username inputbox on Facebook. pass is the HTML ID for the password inputbox on Facebook and login_form is the HTML ID for the button you click to login. There is another way that you can do it via inputboxes. So your computer asks which page you want to navigate to and the username and password for the site that you selected. It looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim x,msgB,inpB,ie,ieDAI,FBU,FBP,GMU,GMP,HMU,HMP,YHU,YHP
Set x=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set ie=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Sub WhiLD
Do While ie.busy
wscript.sleep 200
loop
End Sub
inpB=inputbox("What website would you like to login to?"&vbLf&"Facebook"&vbLF&"Gmail"&vbLF&"Hotmail"&vbLF&"Yahoo")

If inpB="Facebook" then
    On Error Resume Next
    FBU=inputbox("Enter Facebook Username")
    FBP=inputbox("Enter Facebook Password")
    ie.Navigate"www.facebook.com"
    ie.Left=0
    ie.Toolbar=1
    ie.StatusBar=0
    ie.Height=200
    ie.Width=1020
    Call WhiLD
    ie.Document.All.Item("email").Value= FBU
    ie.Document.All.Item("pass").Value= FBP
    ie.Document.All.Item("login_form").Submit
    Call WhilD
    ie.fullscreen=1
    ie.Visible=1
    wscript.quit
    End If

If inpB="Gmail" then
    On Error Resume Next
    GMU=inputbox("Enter Gmail Username")
    GMP=inputbox("Enter Gmail Password")
    ie.Navigate"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/"
    ie.Left=0
    ie.Toolbar=1
    ie.StatusBar=0
    ie.Height=200
    ie.Width=1020
    Call WhiLD
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("Email").Value= GMU
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("Passwd").Value= GMP
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("SignIn").Submit
    Call WhilD
    ie.fullscreen=1
    ie.Visible=1
    wscript.quit
    End If

If inpB="Hotmail" then
    On Error Resume Next
    HMU=inputbox("Enter Hotmail Username")
    HMP=inputbox("Enter Hotmail Password")
    ie.Navigate"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1414030279&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https:%2F%2Fblu168.mail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fmkt%3Den-au%26rru%3Dinbox&lc=3081&id=64855&mkt=en-au&cbcxt=mai"
    ie.Left=0
    ie.Toolbar=1
    ie.StatusBar=0
    ie.Height=200
    ie.Width=1020
    Call WhiLD
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample").Value= HMU
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("idDiv_PWD_PasswordExample").Value= HMP
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("idSIButton9").Submit
    Call WhiLD
    ie.fullscreen=1
    ie.Visible=1
    wscript.quit
    End If

If inpB="Yahoo" then
    On Error Resume Next
    HMU=inputbox("Enter Yahoo Username")
    HMP=inputbox("Enter Yahoo Password")
    ie.Navigate"https://login.yahoo.com/"
    ie.Left=0
    ie.Toolbar=1
    ie.StatusBar=0
    ie.Height=200
    ie.Width=1020
    Call WhiLD
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("username").Value= YHU
    ie.Doucment.All.Item("passwd").Value= YHP
    ie.Doucment.All.Item(".save").Submit
    Call WhiLD
    ie.fullscreen=1
    ie.Visible=1
    wscript.quit
    End If

If inpB=2 then
wscript.quit
End If
```

You can also use a custom IE Explorer. That is what I did before. It could be more efficient but it is easier to learn and understand when it is all layed out like this.

Please Note: None of these VBScripts will work if you are already signed in to the website.

Hope this Helps.